# How to get the name of a column by its index?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Give the dataframe `df`, how can I retrieve the name of a column by its index?
For example, it's possible to get the index of a column by its name as follows: `df.columns.indexOf("col1")`, but I need just the opposite thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`df.columns` gives you an `Array[String]` of each of the column names in order.

`df.columns(index)` will give you the column name of the column at `index`

Answer (score 1):

`dataFrame.colums` gives the list of columns. You can get the column name by `dataFrame.columns(index)`

If you have Data set you can get by

```
ds.schema.fields(index)
```

Hope this helps